# Android opening file with intent doesn't show files

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to have my app open a file selector with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
```

However, this only opens up a screen asking me to select a file from Recents, Google Drive, or my Downloads. I have tried variations of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and `ACTION_PICK`. They all take me to the same screen.

How do I fix it so that it will open up a file selector where I can browse the files on my phone?

Comment: did you try **ACTION_VIEW**

Comment: If you are looking for a file explorer kind of thing, there is no native file explorer provided by android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to have my app open a file selector with the following code

There is no MIME type that begins with `file/`, [according to the people who maintain the roster of valid MIME types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Use `*/*`.

> How do I fix it so that it will open up a file selector where I can browse the files on my phone?

Use the code that you have.

The screen that you cite will look something like this:

[image: Documents UI]

In the overflow, there will be an option named "Show internal storage" (or something like that). Click that, and you will be given an option to browse what the Android SDK calls external storage.